# Creating a Pivot Table with a MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, multi-index

I have a dataframe with a list of countries and correspondent continent as well as various other columns.

Is it possible to create a pivot table with both the continent and the country and an index as level 0 and level 1?

```
ID  Daily Average   Country Continent/Area  FYG YGH 
0   242.148 Australia   Asia Pacific    450 22.5
2   23.656  Brunei  Asia Pacific    35  1.75
5   41.693  Indonesia   Asia Pacific    184 9.2
7   79.112  Malaysia    Asia Pacific    35  1.75
10  30.492  Papua New Guinea    Asia Pacific    32186   1609.3
11  100.871 Russia  Asia Pacific    368 18.4
20  45.337  Trinidad and Tobago Central America 3   0.15
33  16.93   Norway  Europe  54  2.7
44  26.563  Oman    Middle East 544 27.2
45  270.339 Qatar   Middle East 4543    227.15
46  16.875  United Arab Emirates    Middle East 4   0.2
48  34.349  Algeria North Africa    214 10.7
49  5.724   Egypt   North Africa    4531684 226584.2
54  224.645 United States   North America   315 15.75
```

An expected output would looks as follows;

```
                                 Daily Average FYG  YGH
Continent/Area  Country  
Asia Pacific    Australia         242.148     450   225
                Brunei            23.656      35    1.75
                Indonesia         41.693      184   9.2 
                Malaysia          79.112      35    1.75
                Papua New Guinea  30.492      32186 1609.3
Europe          Norway            16.93       54    2.7  
.
.
.

North Africa   Algeria            34.349      214  10.7
               Egypt              5.724       4531684 226584.2
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: How looks expected output?

Comment: Added in an expected output now! Thanks so much!

Comment: ok, dupe is correct.